# I am trying to make a registration form with JAVA, but I can't run my code

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, registration

I have this code and I can't get it to run. I'm new with JAVA. I was trying to make a login and registration form with JAVA swing, and I finished designing GUI part and I also connected the code with mySQL database. But I don't know why that I can't run the code. I tried debugging it, but can't find the bug. I am using eclipse and I also referenced mySQL jar.

Please let me know, if I'm doing anything wrong. Thank you for the help :)

```
package login_register_form;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;


public class RegisterPage implements ActionListener{


JFrame frame;
String[] position = {"Admin", "Manager", "Assistant"};
JTextField firstName;
JTextField lastName;
JTextField userName;
JTextField email;
JPasswordField password;
JPasswordField confirmPW;
JButton registerButton;
JButton cancelButton;
JComboBox jobPosition = new JComboBox(position);

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                RegisterPage window = new RegisterPage();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application. Calling methods from constructor
 */
public RegisterPage() {
    createWindow();     
    initialize();
    actionEvent();
    
}

/**
 * Create a main window
 */
public void createWindow() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Registration Page");
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1113, 806);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    
    
    // panel: orange colored background
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(new Color(255,165,0,200));
    panel.setBounds(300, 150, 500, 472);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    
    // label: scaled background 
    JLabel background = new JLabel("");
    background.setBounds(6, 6, 1100, 772);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/background.jpg"));
    Image img = icon.getImage();
    Image imgScale = img.getScaledInstance(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon scaledIcon = new ImageIcon(imgScale);
    background.setIcon(scaledIcon);
    frame.getContentPane().add(background);
    
    // title: "Register Page"
    JLabel registerPage = new JLabel("Register Page");
    registerPage.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 19));
    registerPage.setBounds(182, 40, 135, 29);
    panel.add(registerPage);
    
    // input: first name        
    firstName = new JTextField();
    firstName.setBounds(145, 76, 210, 32);
    panel.add(firstName);
    firstName.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: last name
    lastName = new JTextField();
    lastName.setBounds(145, 120, 210, 32);
    panel.add(lastName);
    lastName.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: user name
    userName = new JTextField();
    userName.setBounds(145, 164, 210, 32);
    panel.add(userName);
    userName.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: password
    password = new JPasswordField();
    password.setBounds(145, 208, 210, 32);
    panel.add(password);
    
    // input: confirm password
    confirmPW = new JPasswordField();
    confirmPW.setBounds(145, 252, 210, 32);
    panel.add(confirmPW);
    
    // input: email
    email = new JTextField();
    email.setBounds(145, 296, 210, 32);
    panel.add(email);
    email.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: position
    jobPosition.setBounds(145, 340, 210, 32);
    panel.add(jobPosition);
    
    // button: cancel
    JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancelButton.setBounds(109, 400, 117, 40);
    panel.add(cancelButton);
    
    // button: register
    JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");
    registerButton.setBounds(275, 400, 117, 40);
    panel.add(registerButton);
    
    // label: first name
    JLabel fName = new JLabel("First Name");
    fName.setBounds(36, 84, 85, 16);
    panel.add(fName);
    
    // label: last name
    JLabel lName = new JLabel("Last Name");
    lName.setBounds(36, 128, 85, 16);
    panel.add(lName);
    
    // label: user name
    JLabel uName = new JLabel("User Name");
    uName.setBounds(36, 172, 85, 16);
    panel.add(uName);
    
    // label: password
    JLabel pWord = new JLabel("Password");
    pWord.setBounds(36, 216, 85, 16);
    panel.add(pWord);
    
    // label: re-password
    JLabel cPW = new JLabel("Re-Password");
    cPW.setBounds(36, 260, 85, 16);
    panel.add(cPW);
    
    // label: email
    JLabel eMail = new JLabel("Email");
    eMail.setBounds(36, 304, 85, 16);
    panel.add(eMail);
    
    // label: position
    JLabel position = new JLabel("Position");
    position.setBounds(36, 347, 101, 16);
    panel.add(position);
    
    
    
    
    
}
public void actionEvent() {
    // Adding action listener to buttons
    registerButton.addActionListener(this);
    cancelButton.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==registerButton) {
        try {
            //Creating Connection Object
            Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase","root", "root");
            //Prepared Statement
            PreparedStatement Pstatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into student value(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            // Specifying the values of it's parameter
            Pstatement.setString(1, firstName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(2, lastName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(3, userName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(4, password.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(5, confirmPW.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(6, email.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(7, jobPosition.getSelectedItem().toString());
            //Checking for the password match
            if (password.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(confirmPW.getText())) {
                // Executing query
                Pstatement.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Registered Successfully");
            } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password did not match");
            }
        
        
        
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource()==cancelButton) {
        // Clearing Fields
        firstName.setText("");
        lastName.setText("");
        userName.setText("");
        password.setText("");
        confirmPW.setText("");
        email.setText("");
        jobPosition.setSelectedItem("Admin");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: I don't see any error in my code, but I simply can't run my code. When I run the code I can see the icon of Java file on my deck, but it just disappears after few seconds.

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: I run it by clicking the run button on the left corner  of the eclipse IDE.

Comment: In `createWindow()` you are creating a frame but never calling `frame.setVisible(true)`

Comment: So, do you mean that I should add frame.setVisible(true);?

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!